# SSO and IDP proxy for UI and REST

Tags: rest, wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are building a SaaS application (enterprise oriented).
We have to be able to log-in the users against the saml2 IdP of their company with SSO functionality (so multi-tenant context)
We prefer to manage it in a isolated component and so not directly on the application it self.
We think to use a kind of "proxy".
We have two questions :
- Does WSO2 IS is able to act as proxy, delegating the authentication to an extern IdP ?
- Our SaaS application will be offered via UI relying on REST ful services, so we need to manage SSO
also with the services, so for example :
    . The user comes on the UI without any log-in before
    . The company IDP login-page is shown for authentication
    . Once logged , the UI will perform some calls to REST service and we need to secure those service call, to be sure
    the user is allowed to call this service
        How to manage it ?
        Does the "proxy" API can act also as "proxy services" in order to call the extern IDP API ?

Tks 
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly,  There is an existing IDP in "foo" company. In "bar" domain you have applications. You are not going to integrate application directly with IDP in "foo".  And you are wishing to install an another IDP in "bar" domain where this "bar" domain IDP can talks to existing  IDP in "foo" domain.   Yes. WSO2IS can be used to implement such use case. It has "Authentication Framework" for SAML2 SSO logon...  Let me explain it bit. When user is directed to WSO2IS SAML2 IDP,  user can be authenticated by verifying user/password which is the default behavior. (default authenticator that is picked by "Authentication Framework"). But there can be any other authenticators such as SAML2 SSO (where WSO2IS can call to another SAML2 IDP and authenticate the user), OpenID and so on. I guess, same scenario has been discussed [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/08/security-patterns-decentralized.html). I found [blog](http://isharaaruna.blogspot.com/2013/10/federated-saml2-idp-with-wso2is.html) on implementing this.